# Stop Apps from springing to full screen

Tags: windows-7, aero-snap

How do I set the Windows 7 UI from springing applications to full screen when I move them near the top of the screen.  I know there is a Control Panel setting but I'll be damned if I can find it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The feature is called Aero Snap. Here is how to disable it:

1. Control Panel
2. Ease of Access Center
3. Make the mouse easier to use
4. Prevent windows from being automatically arranged when moved to the edge of the screen

Note: If you are using the "Category" layout of Control Panel, you may find the setting under Ease of Access > Change how your mouse works.

Comment: Ah - Yes - Hugs...

Comment: Just a note that disabling this also prevents you from using the `WinKey` + `ArrowKey` functions that can min/max windows, make them take up half the screen or switch between monitors on a multi-monitor system (with the `Shift` key).  To turn off Aero Snap but retain these functions, you have to use a 3rd party app, as detailed [here](http://superuser.com/questions/442118/how-to-disable-windows-7-feature-that-maximizes-a-window-to-full-screen-when-mov).