# How to disable aero snap without disabling Win+Left/Right on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, aero-snap

I've searched the internet and I came across [this post](https://superuser.com/a/222609/557192) but it only solves one half of the problem. The first comment of this answer describes my problem but I could not find any solutions to this 'problem'. So I'm making a new post for this. Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT:**

So it seems there is no build-in way to achieve this. It's basically all or nothing. http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/disable-aero-snap-windows/

> Worth considering, however, is that you’ll also lose the ability to position windows on the right or left side of the screen, minimize, and maximize by using the keyboard <kbd>arrow keys</kbd> while holding the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key. For many users, the mouse-based snap features have a tendency to be annoying, but the keyboard-based window management features are great. It’s a shame that Microsoft treats Aero Snap with an “all or nothing” approach, but users can always turn to a third party window management utility if they miss this functionality.

I don't know where to look for software which provide these functionalities, so I'm open for software suggestions!

**EDIT2:**

There is actually a built-in option to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So after some more searching I've found a way to achieve this.

Found the solution on http://winaero.com/blog/disable-snapping-in-windows-10-but-keep-other-extended-window-management-options/

1. Open Registry Editor and go to the following Registry key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`
2. Modify the string value named **DockMoving**. By default, it has a value data of 1. You need to set it to 0.
3. Sign out from your Windows 10 account and sign back in for the changes to take effect.

[image: Picture]

Comment: This registry edit disables snapping windows to a portion of a screen, but does not disable the most frustrating behavior when you have 2 monitors: you can't drag a window between monitors unless you drag really fast. Dragging at a normal speed causes the cursor to get stuck on the current monitor.

Comment: Try shift-meta(windows key) and left or right for moving your windows between monitors.  The caveat is eventually they appear half-obscured because of a bug in the function.  When they're too high for the top edge of the monitor (which they inevitably will be at some point), hit shift+right click on the taskbar button for the window in question, and select "move" in the menu dialog. Then you can move the windows with your arrow keys. The first movement using arrow keys also triggers an ability for the window to follow your mouse cursor afterwards.

Comment: I enable this and can't drag windows between monitors at all now! This answer disables snapping but makes screen boundaries impossible to traverse. I use a 1000hz high dpi mouse. I find a $2 mouse works better on Windows PCs than gaming mouse? Is Windows not designed for high performance mice?

Answer (score 1):

Previous answer is missing a value. Here is complete change:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"DockMoving"="0"
"SnapSizing"="0"
```

which addresses this problem with the other solution:

> This registry edit disables snapping windows to a portion of a screen, but
> does not disable the most frustrating behavior when you have 2 monitors: you
> can't drag a window between monitors unless you drag really fast. Dragging at
> a normal speed causes the cursor to get stuck on the current monitor.