# How to disable Windows 10 top edge auto maximize 'feature'?

Tags: windows-10, modern-ui-snapping

I hate my apps being maximized when I try to reposition my apps near the top.

I **love the left/right edge snap** though. I just **hate the top edge snap**.

Most tips I found are for Windows 7, they no longer work for Windows 10.

Is there a way to disable Windows 10 top snap / auto maximize 'feature'?

**Edit: I don't want to disable left/right snap, I just want to disable top edge snap.** Because very often when I am trying to move my app to top edge, Windows will maximize it instead of moving, which I find is BS.

Comment: Noone has found a way disable *just the top-edge snap* AFAIK; however, changing the string value `DockMoving` to 0 in the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop` registry key disables the mouse drag edge snapping but leaves the keyboard shortcuts (Win-Left, Win-Right) enabled. Similar/duplicate questions: [How to disable auto-maximize/resize window (aero-snap) when near screen edge?](https://superuser.com/questions/222597/), 
[How to disable aero snap without disabling Win+Left/Right on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1039039/).

Answer (score 3):

Go to:

1. Start menu
2. Settings
3. Search "snap"
4. Switch off "arrange windows automatically by dragging them to the sides or corners of the screen

Comment: I should have made it clearer, I love the left/right snap, I just want to disable the top snap. Edited my question to emphasis that.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my update:

1. Start Menu
2. Settings
3. Search 'snap'
4. switch off 'When I snap a window, automatically size it to fill available space'

Note this won't completely eliminate top snapping, but it doesn't seem to do it as quickly as before AND it doesn't eliminate left/right snap (those are fabulous, I agree).

Comment: thank you.. my quality of life has improved now.