# Is it possible to disable "Snap windows" when moving windows between monitors without disabling the Win+Right/Left Arrow hotkeys

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, windows-snap-assist

If I toggle off "Snap windows" because I want to disable the window snapping that occurs when dragging windows between monitors, it also disables the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> shortcuts for snapping to the right and left of the screen.

I even tried going to "Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > Ease of Access Center > Make the mouse easier to use" and checked "Prevent windows from being automatically arranged when moved to the edge of the screen" in hopes that it would only disable mouse snapping but that seemed to do the same thing as toggling off "Snap windows" because the keyboard hotkeys don't work when that checked either.

Is there a way in Windows 10 to disable snapping when moving between monitors but keep the shortcuts?

Comment: No, I remember finding that and it not working but I was able to find a solution which I posted as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution! It can be fixed with the following command line...

> reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Mouse" /v DockTargetMouseWidth /t
>   REG_DWORD /d 0
>
> Run that from a command prompt and reboot. You won't have the problem
>   any more.
>
> It creates HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse !
>   DockTargetMouseWidth and sets the value to 0.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/7m01h1/is_there_a_fix_for_my_mouse_getting_stuck_between/

Answer (score 0):

I think your question was already answered by this [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1039039/how-to-disable-aero-snap-without-disabling-winr-winl-on-windows-10) question. What you need to do is to open Regedit, navigate to: "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" and either modify or create (if there is none) the *DockMoving* string value to 0. After that sign out of windows than sign in again.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks a bunch! This is exactly what I needed to know. I swear I searched everywhere for a solution to this before posting my question. After taking a look at your link to where it was already answered, I can see I was not searching for the right keywords. I had no clue it was called aero snap for one lol and I was typing the hotkeys differently.

Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. I am glad I could help.

Comment: Not sure when exactly but at some point my mouse started getting stuck at the edge of my monitors again but DockMoving was still set to 0. It seems like it is now just disabling the ability to dock a window to half of the screen with your mouse but no longer disabling whatever it is that makes the mouse want to stick to the edge of each monitor when trying to move windows between them.

Comment: I set DockMoving = 0 and now snapping is disabled but windows still get stuck between monitors. Did this used to work and MS removed the ability or am I missing a step?